# How do I set the xml namespace when using Jersey, jaxb & jax-rs

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

How do I set the xml namespace when using Jersey, jaxb & jax-rs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all done using JAXB annotations.  The points below refer to your domain model.

**Schema Level**

You can specify schema level namespace information using the @XmlSchema package level annotation:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.org",
           elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package org.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

The above annotation leveraging elementFormDefault will default the namespace of all elements to "http://www.example.org".

**Type Level**

You can override namespaces at the type level using the @XmlType annotation:

```
@XmlType(namespace="http://www.example.org/foo")
```

**Property/Field Level**

And/or you can specify namespace information on the annotations themselves:

- @XmlAttribute(namespace="http://www.example.org/bar")
- @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.org/bar")
- @XmlElementWrapper(namespace="http://www.example.org/bar")
- @XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.example.org/bar")

**Example**

I have a blog post that demonstrates these concepts with an example:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html